# usage of strdup

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{    
    char *s;
    s = strdup("foo");
    printf("%s\n", s);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Looks pretty harmless, doesn't it ?
But my IDE, which is Dev-C++, gives my the following warning:
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

The warning disappears if you would change the code like this:

```
char *s;
s = (char*)strdup("foo");
```

[image]

Can anyone help me explain this?

Comment: 'Looks pretty harmless, doesn't it ?' -- Looks wrong since strdup wasn't declared.

Comment: Did you open and look at string.h? Did you find the declaration for `strdup()`? What is the return type?

Comment: @JonathanWood, the definition is `_CRTIMP char* __cdecl  _strdup (const char*) __MINGW_ATTRIB_MALLOC;`

Comment: @JimBalter, Please check my update for the question

Comment: And does string.h declare strdup on your system? It's not a part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @JimBalter, (1) I'm writing c code. (2) it is in string.h. Please see my comment for JonathanWood.

Comment: It may be in string.h but it's conditional on preprocessor definitions, as it must be to conform with the standards.

Comment: 'I'm writing c code' -- strdup isn't in the C standard either.

Comment: @JimBalter, agree. It's not.

Comment: @FihopZz Please update your IDE: http://sourceforge.net/directory/os:windows/freshness:recently-updated/?q=Dev-C%2B%2B

Comment: `_strdup` and `strdup` are not the same name...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using  Dev-C++, but strdup is not part of the C or C++ standard, it's a POSIX function. You need to define the proper (according to your IDE's documentation) preprocessor symbols in order for strdup to be declared by the header file ... this is necessary in order for the header file not to pollute the name space when included into conforming C or C++ source files.

For a simple portable alternative, consider

```
char* mystrdup(const char* s)
{
    char* p = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
    if (p) strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}
```

Or, if you know strdup is actually in the library, you can copy its declaration from string.h into your own source file or header ... or use the simpler declaration from the man page:

```
char *strdup(const char *s);
```

Comment: thanks very much. I'll try to figure out how to define the proper preprocessor symbols.

Comment: @FihopZz Be sure you have "strict ANSI" or similar switch turned off.

Answer (score 6):

That's not right. `strdup` returns `char *` already. Something else is wrong. Probably because you did not include the right header file that declares the true return type for this function.

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: This. The assumed return type for an undeclared function is `int`, which explains the warning message.

Comment: Note on some compilers such as gcc you might need to also define a feature macro e.g._BSD_SOURCE

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `#include <string.h>`.  In the absence of function signatures, strdup is assumed by the compiler to return an int, hence the warning.

Answer (score 1):

`man strdup`

you will get following things

```
#include<string.h>

char* strdup(const char * s);
```

so `strdup()` returns `char*` there shuld not be any problem
Actually in your case it takes implicit declaration of `strdup()` so by default return type is `int` hence you get this warning

Either `include<string.h>`

or

give forward declaration `char* strdup(const char *);`

Also don't forget to `free(s)` in last when all usage are done

Comment: What ?? if include proper header file then should not be a problem

Comment: @FihopZz : On my gcc 4.5.2 it's working fine may be due to the problem with devc++ platform .. if `#include<string.h>` is not working ,then use my second answer ..give forward declaration as i have written and check it .. and let me know

Comment: @FihopZz: actually in header file compiler only check the declaration in this example so .. you can give declaration manually and it will work

Comment: 'On my gcc 4.5.2 it's working fine' -- it won't if you use any of the options that turn off extensions and use only standard C.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your original answer.